# How to send zip file on email using password protected and unzip it via email in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip

I need to send a zip file via Email (or any other sharing app), and the zip file  is password protected. When I download that zip file it will ask for the password. I am using `SSZipArchive` to zip my html file.

```
  NSString *txtFilePath0 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"medical_checkups.html"];
  NSArray *inputPaths = @[txtFilePath0];
  [SSZipArchive createZipFileAtPath:archivePath withFilesAtPaths:inputPaths withPassword:@"123456"];
  NSString *archivePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/medical_checkups.zip"];
 MFMailComposeViewController *_mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
                if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
                {

                    [_mailController setMessageBody:@""
                                             isHTML:NO];
                    [_mailController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
                    [_mailController addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:archivePath]
                                              mimeType:@"application/zip"
                                              fileName:@"medical_checkups.zip"];
                    [self presentViewController:_mailController animated:YES completion:nil];

                }
```

But now when I try to unzip my zip file there is no popup for password. I also can't open my zip file.

Answer (score 2):

For password protection you have to use This library https://cocoapods.org/pods/SSZipArchive

Then get your Zip file convert to `NSData` and Attach in Mail composer

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

NSString *WritableDBPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename]; 

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:WritableDBPath];

[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/zip" fileName:@"/abc.zip"];
[picker setSubject:@"Database"];

[picker setMessageBody:@"Database testing" isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

**---Edited**

**Archive Utility** 
Will show you error while extracting (unzip) your file because its password protected.

[image]

So , to unzip the Your zip file outside your Application then

please use 
[the-unarchiver](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353) Application for Mac

**---Edited**

By @[Priti Kanauziya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7955963/priti-kanauziya), 
I found the new solution . In SSZipArchive there is a new class AES and its YES by default . And we need to set it NO .

Comment: Thanks for comment . But i am already doing the same thing . Please have look my question once again .

Comment: I found the new solution . In SSZipArchive there is a new class AES and its YES by default . And we need to set it NO . That's it .